# ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module ng2-img-tools

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm trying to use the `ng2-img-tools` package with Angular4 and running into this error:

`ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module ~/client/node_modules/ng2-img-tools/dist/ng2-img-tools.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in ~/client/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in ~/client/src/app/app.module.ts`

I brute-forced by trying every version of the said package available.. but still running into the error above.. Any help?

Here's my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular2-flash-messages": "1.0.8",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ng2-dnd": "^2.2.2",
    "ng2-img-tools": "^1.1.3",
    "ng2-select": "^1.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Appmodule import change row

import { Ng2ImgToolsModule } from 'ng2-img-tools';   //Delete row

import { Ng2ImgToolsModule } from "ng2-img-tools/dist/src/ng2-img-tools.module"; // Add row